# Ubuntu froze during upgrade to 13.10

Tags: installation, unity, 13.10

My computer boots into Ubuntu, but there are issues with the way Unity loads up. There is nothing on the panel in the top right corner of my desktop, although the Launcher appears.

I tried safe mode and recovery mode, but I was unable to repair it or start with networking mode.

How do I proceed? Should I try to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7 again?

Comment: Hi Kiran, could you add some details? The installation procedure you followed for example, any errors that you faced. That would help in making the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to do a new install of Ubuntu 13.10 from DVD or USB Flash and select the Update option on the install menu...